# Discrete Fourier Transform: Proof that the set of vector $w_k[n] = e^{j\omega kn}$ for $n = 0,...,N-1$ is a basis for $\mathbb{C}^N$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, orthogonality

$$
w_k[n] = e^{j\frac{2p}{N}nk}
$$
where

- $k = 0,1,...,N-1$ is the index of the vector
- $n = 0,1,...,N-1$ is the index of the element of each vector
  (i.e. $N-1$ vectors each of size $N-1$)
  is an orthogonal basis in $\mathbb{C}^N$

In vector notation
$$
w^{(k)}_{k = 0,1,...,N-1}
$$
with
$$
w_n^{(k)} = e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk}
$$
is an orthogonal basis in $\mathbb{C}^N$

Proof
\begin{align*}
  \langle\textbf{w}^{(k)}, \textbf{w}^{(h)} \rangle &=\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} \big(e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk\big)^\star} e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}nh}\\
  &=\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}(h-k)n}\\
  &=\begin{cases}
    N &\text{ for } h = k\\
    \frac{1-e^{j2\pi(h-k)}}{1-e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}(h-k)}} = 0 &\text{ otherwise (i.e. for $h\ne k$)}
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

**My question**:
How do we prove that
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}(h-k)n} = \frac{1-e^{j2\pi(h-k)}}{1-e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}(h-k)}} = 0 \quad \text{for $h\ne k$}
$$
?

Comment: Geometric series

Comment: indeed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series many thanks @marwalix